# Write interface of type object in typescript interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface, angular-test

This is my Data Structure how do I write an interface for it?

```
const TransitReport: {
        title: string;
        client: string;
        data: {
            overdueReviews: number;
            outstandingCovenantBreaches: number;
            outstandingMarginingBreaches: number;
            periodStartDate: string;
            periodEndDate: string;
        };
    }[]
```

I tried this:

```
export interface TransitReport {
  title: string;
  client?: string;
  data: Record<string, unknown>;
  overdueReviews: number;
  outstandingCovenantBreaches: number;
  outstandingMarginingBreaches: number;
  periodStartDate: string;
  periodEndDate: string;
}
```

This kinda works for mock API calling for data but when writing test cases I stuck with the error of:

Type '

```
{ title: string; 
client: string; 
data: { 
overdueReviews: number; 
outstandingCovenantBreaches: number; 
outstandingMarginingBreaches: number; 
periodStartDate: string;
periodEndDate: string; 
}; }'
```

is missing the following properties from type
'TransitReport': overdueReviews, outstandingCovenantBreaches, outstandingMarginingBreaches, periodStartDate, periodEndDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break your interface `TransitReport` as below code snippet, because you need to provide `overdueReviews, periodEndDate` etc.. under data record. Otherwise it'll check those properties under your root `TransitReport` object, where it's not present.

```
export interface TransitReport {
    title: string;
    client?: string;
    data: DataRecord;
}

export interface DataRecord {
    overdueReviews: number;
    outstandingCovenantBreaches: number;
    outstandingMarginingBreaches: number;
    periodStartDate: string;
    periodEndDate: string;
}
```

Comment: Welcome!.. Ritik